# About next 3 odd and even number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function NumberInput() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setErrorMessage('');

    // Only allow positive numbers
    if (value < 0) {
      setErrorMessage('Please enter a positive number');
      return;
    }

    // Only allow numbers
    if (isNaN(value)) {
      setErrorMessage('Please enter a valid number');
      return;
    }

    setInputValue(value);

    if (value % 2 === 0) {
      // If the number is even, show the next 3 even numbers
      const nextEvens = [value + 2, value + 4, value + 6];
      setErrorMessage(`The next even numbers are: ${nextEvens.join(', ')}`);
    } else {
      // If the number is odd, show the next 3 odd numbers
      const nextOdds = [value + 2, value + 4, value + 6];
      setErrorMessage(`The next odd numbers are: ${nextOdds.join(', ')}`);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="number-input">Enter a number:</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        id="number-input"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />
      {errorMessage && <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>{errorMessage}</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default NumberInput;
```

Question is Create a simple UI with one input field that accepts only numbers.
If the user types negative numbers, show "enter a positive value".
If the user types an even number, show the next 3 even numbers.
If the user types an odd number, show the next 3 odd numbers.

and i think logic is correct but i can't get the proper answer

ex  - i type a even number but couldn't get the correct next three even number

Answer (score 1):

You got bitten by something that every webdeveloper has run into at some time... A input fields value will always be a string and not a number, which is why, if `value = 2` ,`value + 2` will be 22 and not 4... So coerce the string into a number before working with it.

FYI: Modern browsers support a new property on event.target that will return the inputs value as number which is `event.taget.valueAsNumber`